# Subdomain doesn't work sometimes

Tags: web, dns

I can't figure out, but sometimes my website's subdomain doesn't respond and I can't resolve its name, so if `mywebsite.org` works fine, `dev.mywebsite.org` does not. Then in less then one hour it starts working again without any intrusion from my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are not able to resolve subdomain its a DNS issue. Try to narrow down the issue by using `dig` or `nslookup` to query the results from your authoritative nameserver and also with the DNS server near you (which is in /etc/resolv.conf file). I suspect your local DNS server is misbehaving.

Comment: The problem is that other people who try to access the same domain have the same issue. And they're far away from me so we aren't using the same "local" dns servers.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but DNS records for domain haven't changed for weeks.

Comment: Then the problem is with the `authoritative` nameserver. And sorry for misleading you with my previous comment (delete)  DNS propagation is not required for subdomains.